# Use case for kubernetes job restart policy

Tags: kubernetes

Reading the kubernetes documentation jobs accept two values for the restart policy. If set to OnFailure, the job restarts the pod if it's unsuccsesful, if it's set to Never it creates a new pod. I cannot think on a situation where I would prefer one over the other, their outcomes seem equivalent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One use case would be to keep some files that are useful for your Job.

If you use any `emptyDir` volume in your Pod (in general, not necessary related to Pods created by Jobs only), recreating or rescheduling the Pod will completely delete the content of the `emptyDirs`.

Let's say that your program is very long to execute, but it creates some cache files that could be reused in a next execution of the program. In case of a failure during the program, having `restartPolicy` set to `Never` could be counterproductive since the Pod will be recreated, and therefore you will lose those cache files.

However, if only a container in a Pod crashes, the emptyDir content is unaffected. Therefore having the `restartPolicy` set to `OnFailure` could help us reuse those cache files for our long program.